# Usersettings Upgrade not working

Tags: c#, settings

I am storing some Usersettings using the ApplicationSettingsBase system in c#.

Everything works fine except when i update to a new version. In this case always the default settings(App.Conf) are used.

I already created an UpdateSettings (Default true) Setting:

```
public MainWindow() {
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.UpdateSettings) {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
        Properties.Settings.Default.UpdateSettings = false;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

When running this part of code a settings file is created under `\AppData\Local\Company\NameOfSoftware_Url_somehash\versionnumber`. Sometimes the hash differs, so a new folder is created. In this newly created config file, there is only 1 entry written:

```
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <XXX.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="UpdateSettings" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
        </XXX.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

When i close the program the default settings from the app.Conf file are saved.

What am i doing wrong.

I am using .net framework 4.0

Comment: Have you tried to really step through the exit using the debugger? It's hard to say what the error might be, are this the only place where you use/read/update these settings?